# I can't register components using React_on_Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-on-rails

The registration was working fine with the default HelloWorld app, but once I deleted the folder and created my own, it stopped working.

I made a new folder under app/bundles called posts with a startup folder.

In the startup folder, I'm registering the components like so:

```
import ReactOnRails from 'react-on-rails';

import PostContainer from '../containers/PostContainer';

ReactOnRails.register({
  PostContainer
});
```

The PostContainer.jsx file is in the containers folder and it looks like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

export default class PostsContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <PostList posts={this.props.posts} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/bundles/HelloWorld/startup/registration',
  ],
```

I tried changing the HelloWorld to posts or Posts, but it did not work.

Am I supposed to have a file called webpack.configure.build.js? Or is the webpack.config.js the file I need to edit?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can we get file paths for all these files?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the component to the erb view file with the associated props passed in? You would need to add the props within your Posts controller or whichever controller is rendering your Posts view. I'm pretty sure you would then need to add a line in your webpack config:

```
config: {
  'webpack-bundle': [
    '...',
    './app/bundles/Posts/startup/registration'
  ]
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= react_component("PostsContainer", props: @posts_props, prerender: false) %>
```

Also make sure in your layout file you have:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'webpack-bundle' %>
```

Note: `PropTypes` should be imported from the `prop-types` package now. The react team plucked that package out of the react core as of recent.